# C++ Getline not always getting line in multiple forked processes in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, fork, getline

I am trying to make a program to create multiple processes that each read a line out of the console, then do stuff with it. I am having trouble with the `getline(cin, temp)` only sometimes reading a line.  The input buffer is already loaded with 4 lines of text.

EDIT: I need to use fork, which creates multiple processes (rather than threads) in order to use `wait`, which waits for the first child process to finish, and then continues.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

using namespace std;

int childprog();

int main() 
{

    pid_t childpid;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        if ((childpid = fork()) == 0) //Child process
        {
            childprog();
            return 0;
        }
    }

    if (childpid != 0) //If Parent
    {
        wait(0);
        //Stuff
        return 0;
    }
}

int childprog()
{
    string temp;
    getline(cin, temp);
    cout << temp << endl; //Actually do other stuff, just here for debugging
    return 0;
}
```

While it should print out:

```
string number one
string number two
string number three
string number four
```

It prints out:

```
string number one

string number two
string number three
```

or

```
(blank line)
string number one

string number two
```

with the blank lines in any of the possible positions.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE] please?

Comment: OK, done. The program is completely runable @πάνταῥεῖ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution after @JasonLang posted his answer informing me that it was an access problem.  I corrected it by simply moving the reading of the input buffer to before the `fork()`, ensuring that only one process will try to read it at once.

I replaced this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
{
    if ((childpid = fork()) == 0) //Child process
    {
        childprog();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

with this:

```
string temp;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
{
    getline(cin, temp);
    if ((childpid = fork()) == 0) //Child process
    {
        childprog(temp);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

and this:

```
int childprog()
{
    string temp;
    getline(cin, temp);
    cout << temp << endl; //Actually do other stuff, just here for debugging
    return 0;
}
```

with this:

```
int childprog(string input)
{
    cout << input << endl; //Actually do other stuff, just here for debugging
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that each thread is accessing a shared resource: getline and the input buffer. Some operations are atomic, and others can be interrupted.

That means that the exact timing of the operations can interfere with each other. For example, two threads check which line is next to read, they both get told the same line. Then it's a "race condition" to see which ones reads it first and the other thread gets an empty line.

You need to somehow lock getline so that each thread can read a line before the others sneak in and try and take some of the data. An even better solution is to just avoid two processes dealing with the same data, but assuming you can't, then you can use a Mutex.

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/05/c-mutex-examples/

A stripped down example of how a mutex is used:

```
#include<pthread.h>
#include<unistd.h>

pthread_mutex_t lock;

int childprog()
{
    // Put the mutex lock and unlock around the minimum amount of code    
    // which needs to be an "atomic operation". While "locked" other 
    // threads won't run this bit of code, so keep it brief. However, 
    // Locking and unlocking is itself an expensive operation, so you
    // should be careful to minimize the number of times it happens

    string temp;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    getline(cin, temp);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

    cout << temp << endl;

    return 0;
}

// the rest of your program here
```

However note that there's also a line need to initialize the mutex before you used it

```
pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL)
```

And the linked example is using pthread create, not fork

Comment: I need to use `wait`, which does not work with threads, only separate processes.  Mutex only works with threads, as processes run in seperate memory spaces.